# Как создать массив вещественных чисел с рандомными значениями при помощь итераторов

Tags: массивы, ruby

Чтобы создать массив случайных вещественных значений в Ruby  можно использовать циклы. И тогда код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
n = 10
a = []
rnd = Random.new
index = 0 
while index < n
    p a[index] = rnd.rand(-10.99..10.99)
    index += 1
end
```

Не могу разобраться, как достичь подобного результата при помощи итераторов.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
a = 10.times.map{ Random.rand(-10.99..10.99) }
```

В `a` будет нужный массив.

Comment: Таким образом новый массив не создается, создается лишь вещественное число. Проблема заключается в создании массива.

Comment: @ToshiDono Я поправил ответ. В переменной `a` будет массив вещественных чисел.

Comment: благодарю! Буду дальше разбираться в итераторах)

Answer (score 0):

```
Array(10){ rand(-10.99..10.99) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = Array.new(5) {Array.new(4, rand(1..5))}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]